# First inserted value always pushed to rear of sorted skip list c++

Tags: c++, list, skip-lists

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std; // TESTING ONLY

class SkipList
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        Node(int value, int level)
        {
            this->value = value;
            next = new Node*[level];
        }

        Node **next;
        int value;
    };

    Node *head = new Node(0, maxLevel);
    int maxLevel;

    public:

    SkipList()
    {
        maxLevel = 10;
        srand((int)time(nullptr));

        head->next = new Node*[maxLevel];
        for (int i = 0; i < maxLevel; i++)
        {
            head->next[i] = nullptr;
        }
    }

    int promotion()
    {
        int level = 0;
        int _rand = rand() % 2;
        while (_rand)
        {
            level++;
            _rand = rand() % 2;
        }
        return level;
    }

    void Insert(int value)
    {
        int level = promotion();
        Node *newNode = new Node(value, level);

        Node *curr = head;
        for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (curr->next[i] != nullptr)
            {
                while (value > curr->next[i]->value && curr->next[i]->next[i] != nullptr)
                {
                    curr = curr->next[i];
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= level; i++)
        {
            newNode->next[i] = curr->next[i];
            curr->next[i] = newNode;
        }
    }

    void print() const
    {
        Node *cur = head->next[0];
        cout << "List: NULL --> ";
        while (cur != nullptr)
        {
            cout << cur->value << " --> ";
            cur = cur->next[0];
        }
        cout << "NULL";
        cout << endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    SkipList skip;

    skip.Insert(3);
    skip.Insert(2);
    skip.Insert(50);
    skip.Insert(39);
    skip.Insert(2000);
    skip.Insert(500);
    skip.print();

    cout << endl << endl;
    system("pause"); // TESTING
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the above code the first element inserted (in this example 3) is always the last element in the list. Every other elements inserts in the correct order. The above program displays 2-39-50-500-2000-3. I could insert a further 100 values and they would all slot into the correct positions except that first element inserted will always be last, no matter if I place a larger value.

I cannot quite put my finger on it but obviously it's ignoring the last element of the list when placing the insert. Appreciate if someone could shed some light on this. Thanks!

Comment: There seems to be quite a lot wrong with the code beyond the cause of the symptom you are describing.  If I understand your code correctly, you are allocating a random size next[] when you create each node, but you are using a size of 10 for every node.  If you use more than you allocated, you corrupt memory.

Comment: True, head should only be as high as the highest random size. I plan or changing that and other things once I get this bug sorted.

Comment: After commenting and answering (for the specific bug you asked about and the major problem that exists regardless of what you are trying to do) I think I finally guessed what you are trying to do (which is less obvious in your code than you might think).  If my guess is correct, you need a significant restructuring.  I think you want multiple linked lists, where each node is in every list up to its level, but skipped in every higher level list.  If so, then your flow of finding the right predecessor then inserting is wrong.  You may need to insert after many different predecessors at once.

Comment: I think you want the two level loops combined rather than separate.  After you find the correct predecessor at level i, you want to immediately connect the new node in that position at level i only (conditional on the new node's level being high enough).  Then you decrement i and find the correct predecessor at that lower level, which may not be the same as the higher level correct predecessor.  Then my earlier issue with exceeding the size of `next[]` vanishes without being explicitly fixed, and more importantly you build the data structure I think you intend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        if (curr->next[i] != nullptr)
        {
            while (value > curr->next[i]->value && curr->next[i]->next[i] != nullptr)
            {
                curr = curr->next[i];
            }
        }
```

I think there is much more wrong.  But the specific bug you asked about is obvious in the above while.  It always stops before the last item.  I think you should drop the `if` and change the while to:

```
        while (curr->next[i] != nullptr && value > curr->next[i]->value )
        {
            curr = curr->next[i];
        }
```

Notice that in your original code, both the `if` and the `curr->next[i]->next[i]` test are defending against `curr->next[i]->value` seg faulting.  You need to stop the `curr->next[i]->value` test before the last item is reached.  But you don't want to stop the `curr = curr->next[i];` before the last item could be reached.  To do that, I reversed the two sides of your && so I could safely remove one level of indirection from one of them.  I hope that explanation was clear enough.

Comment: Thanks! Works great! Besides the issue mentioned previously is there any other fundamental issues?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= level; i++)
        {
            newNode->next[i] = curr->next[i];
            curr->next[i] = newNode;
        }`  I don't understand how you can manage without knowing the independent level of each node.  In the above loop, you know `newNode->next[]` is big enough, but after you are deeper than head, you don't know that `curr->next[]` is big enough.  Then depending on how that is resolved, you may have a version of this same flaw in the earlier loop.  For other fundamental issues, I expect there are.  But I'd need to see code with that one fixed first to really decide.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment on the original question.

```
for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
{
    // Find the right predecessor at level i.
    while (curr->next[i] != nullptr value > curr->next[i]->value && )
    {
        curr = curr->next[i];
    }
    // link in this node only if its level is high enough
    if ( i < level )
    {
        newNode->next[i] = curr->next[i];
        curr->next[i] = newNode;
    }
}
```

But if I understand your intent correctly, you also need to fix `promotion()` because the design depends on level>0 but promotion does not provide that.  Your original code used `<=level` so it generally used one more position in `next[]` than had been allocated.  My corrected code used level more reasonably.  If instead you want level 0 to be valid, fix the node constructor so you can safely switch to `<=` in my `i < level`